# Visibilizar un div segun click en <h3> con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página con un html con un `div` para mostrar informacion.
El `div` contiene un `h3` de título que al hacer `click` sobre el se depliega.

El problema es que no consigo que se muestre uno de los `div` y se cierren los que esten abiertos al hacer `click` en otro `h3`.

He probado con asignar `AddEventListener` pero no acabo de ver como funciona...

El código que tengo es:

```js
function desplegarMenu(evento) {
  if (document.getElementById("Informacion1").style.display === "none") {
    document.getElementById("Informacion1").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Informacion1").style.display = "none";
  }
}

let desplegables = document.querySelectorAll('.ajudadiv');

desplegables.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', desplegarMenu)
})
```

```html
<div class="faq-item">
  <div class="ajudadiv">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><span class="left-icons ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Informacion 1<span class="loadAnim floatRight hidden"><img class="loadSpinner" src="img/ajax-loader-redmond.gif" style="display: none;"></span></h3>
    <div id="Informacion1" class="tblListingDefault hidden" style="display: none;">
      Informacion 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ajudadiv">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ajudadiv"><span class="left-icons ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Informacion 2<span class="loadAnim floatRight hidden"><img class="loadSpinner" src="img/ajax-loader-redmond.gif" style="display: none;"></span></h3>
    <div id="Informacion2" class="tblListingDefault hidden" style="display: none;">
      Informacion 2
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres hacer es un [acordión](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Comment: Pues sí! ;) Muchas gracias

Comment: He implementado las dos opciones que me habeis dado y me salta el error: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
    <anonymous> ajuda.php:39
Muchas gracias pero por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Las has probado aquí mismo, en las respuestas? Si lo haces, verás que ambas funcionan.

Comment: Sí, la verdad no lo entiendo. Vuestros ejemplos me funcionan perfectamente en stackoverflow però no en mi servidor :( He provado con diferentes navegadores pero el error que me marca es el mismo... Tambien he cambiado document.querySelectorAll por document.getElementById("faq-item") y pasar la id al div y tampoco... No sé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basándome en el ejemplo que publicas y quitando todo lo no esencial, he preparado el siguiente ejemplo que hace un *acordión* del pobre, con puro javascript.

La idea básica es mostrar un *detalle* de información a la vez, por lo que se mantiene una *memoria* del último elemento que ha sido mostrado.

Luego, dado que estamos asociando el evento al clic en el *div* padre del título y del contenido, al lanzarse el evento lo que tenemos que hacer es encontrar el contenido. Para ello, primero me valgo de encontrar el título con `firstElementChild` y luego el contenido con `nextElementSibling`.

Finalmente, ajustar el `display` del estilo a `block` para el elemento que se desea hacer visible y a `none` para el último que se había hecho visible.

```js
let ultimoAbierto;

function desplegarMenu(evento) {
  if (typeof ultimoAbierto !== 'undefined') {
    ultimoAbierto.style.display = "none";
  }
  let titulo = this.firstElementChild;
  let info = titulo.nextElementSibling;
  info.style.display = "block";
  ultimoAbierto = info;
}

let desplegables = document.querySelectorAll('.ajudadiv');

desplegables.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', desplegarMenu)
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ajudadiv">
    <h3>Información 1</h3>
    <div id="Informacion1" style="display: none;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ajudadiv">
    <h3>Información 2</h3>
    <div id="Informacion2" style="display: none;">
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
      mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ajudadiv">
    <h3>Información 3</h3>
    <div id="Informacion3" style="display: none;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El código, como siempre, dice más que mil palabras.

Puedes probarlo aquí mismo haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.

Comment: jachguate con tu codigo el inspector no me muestra ningun error pero no se despliega ninguno de los divs. Aquí en stackoverflow si que me funciona

Comment: Creo que debes ir paso a paso. Dejé este mismo ejemplo en github, dónde se ve claramente que funciona también desde un servidor. Es al ir adaptándolo a tu código que se pierde, si vas paso a paso y mejoras tu técnica de depuración, seguro lo logras. El ejemplo: https://jachguate.github.io/SOExercises/597920/acordion.html

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda ya me funciona! Puede ser porque el código del script lo incluia en el head? Y perdon por mi poco conocimiento de javascript...

Comment: Si incluyes el código en el head, puede que se ejecute antes de cargar el HTML y por lo mismo el querySelector no devuelva los elementos que esperas y no se termina agregando el _event listener_.. El head está bien para scripts que no dependen en nada del DOM. Muchos usan bibliotecas como jQuery para ejecutar código hasta que el DOM está completo y asegurarse de que funcione bien en todos los navegadores.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion! Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Usar delegación de evento al agregar el `AddEventListener` sobre el `div` con clase `.faq-item`.
- Al hacer `click` sobre un `<h3>`, dentro del `div.faq-item`:

  - Buscamos los `.tblListingDefault:not(hidden)` y los ocultamos.
  - Buscamos el `.tblListingDefault` hermano del `<h3>` y lo mostramos

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function desplegarMenu(evento) {
  let h3 = evento.target;
  if (h3.tagName !== 'H3') return; // No es un H3
  
  let faq = document.querySelector('.faq-item');
  // Buscamos los no ocultos y los ocultamos
  faq.querySelectorAll('.tblListingDefault:not(hidden)').forEach(e => e.classList.add('hidden'))
  // Motramos solo el hermano del H3
  h3.parentElement.querySelector('.tblListingDefault').classList.remove('hidden')
}

document.querySelector('.faq-item').addEventListener('click', desplegarMenu)
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-item">
  <div class="ajudadiv">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><span class="left-icons ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Informacion 1<span class="loadAnim floatRight hidden"><img class="loadSpinner" src="img/ajax-loader-redmond.gif" style="display: none;"></span></h3>
    <div id="Informacion1" class="tblListingDefault hidden">
      Informacion 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ajudadiv">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><span class="left-icons ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Informacion 2<span class="loadAnim floatRight hidden"><img class="loadSpinner" src="img/ajax-loader-redmond.gif" style="display: none;"></span></h3>
    <div id="Informacion2" class="tblListingDefault hidden">
      Informacion 2
    </div>
  </div>
```